# redirecting url for pushstate support to .html url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pushstate

I'm working with  html5 pushState(), but if i wanna load the site by a pushState URL it returns 404.

Therefore i need to rewrite all /somePushStateURL to /somePushStateURL.html to get to the right site.

How the right htaccess entry will look like ? 
Are there some other solutions for my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L,R]
```

Comment: i tryed this one,
the /someurl isnt't redirected it's still /someurl after i changed the htaccess,
but instead of returning 404 it returns page not found.

Comment: Do you want URL to change also in the browser?

Comment: Try `R` flag, i.e. in 2nd line: `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L,R]`

Comment: I  want  the right content loaded from the sameUrl with the .html fragment.
It isn't necessary if the .html fragment is displayed or not. 
The Url with ".html" will be changed by pushState anyways.